# WebGL игра на Unity ошибки

Tags: unity3d, webgl

*Создаю игру на Unity для Яндекс игр*

Сама игра в движке и при билде на Android, и ПК ведет себя нормально. Но когда я собираюсь билдить под WebGl при билде происходят ошибки:

[image: Ошибки]

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилятор не может скомпилировать javascript код из-за неопределенного имени\символа.
Скорее всего ошибка в имени метода **GerReward**

Comment: Спасибо! Удачи!